# Type The type cannot be a superinterface of Do; a superinterface must be an interface

Tags: java

```
package Util.Methods;

import API.CustomEvents.MiniEventsEndEvent;
import API.CustomEvents.MiniEventsLeaveEvent;
import API.Info.ApiDo;
import Mains.MiniEvents;
import Mains.SettingsManager;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

import java.util.Set;

public class Do extends ApiDo {
    SettingsManager settings = SettingsManager.getInstance();

    public MiniEvents plugin;

    public Do(MiniEvents plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public void endEvent(boolean removeAll) {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().callEvent(new MiniEventsEndEvent(plugin.getEventName(), removeAll));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadPlayerInventory(final Player p) throws NullPointerException {
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                p.getInventory().clear();
                p.getInventory().setArmorContents(null);
                FileConfiguration fc = plugin.playerFile(p.getName().toLowerCase());
                Set<String> a = fc.getConfigurationSection(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".inv.").getKeys(false);

                for (String s : a) {
                    p.getInventory().setItem(Integer.parseInt(s), fc.getItemStack(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".inv." + s));
                }
                p.getInventory().setHelmet(fc.getItemStack(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".armor.103"));
                p.getInventory().setChestplate(fc.getItemStack(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".armor.102"));
                p.getInventory().setLeggings(fc.getItemStack(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".armor.101"));
                p.getInventory().setBoots(fc.getItemStack(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".armor.100"));

                if (fc.getConfigurationSection(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion") != null) {
                    for (String m : fc.getConfigurationSection(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name.").getKeys(false)) {
                        String s = fc.getString(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name." + m + ".type");
                        int n = fc.getInt(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name." + m + ".level");
                        int i = fc.getInt(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name." + m + ".duration");
                        p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.getByName(s), i, n));
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 20L);
    }
    @Override
    public void putPlayerInSpectate(final Player player) {
        plugin.getSpectateMode().inspec.add(player.getName());
        if (settings.getData().getConfigurationSection(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.") != null) {
            World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(settings.getData().getString(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.world"));
            double x = settings.getData().getDouble(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.x");
            double y = settings.getData().getDouble(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.y");
            double z = settings.getData().getDouble(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.z");
            float yaw = Float.intBitsToFloat(settings.getData().getInt(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.yaw"));
            float pitch = Float.intBitsToFloat(settings.getData().getInt(plugin.getEventName() + ".spec.pitch"));
            final Location l = new Location(w, x, y, z, yaw, pitch);
            Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    player.getInventory().clear();
                    player.getInventory().setArmorContents(null);
                    player.teleport(l);
                    plugin.send(player, "now-in-spectate");
                }
            }, 3L);
        } else {
            Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    player.getInventory().clear();
                    player.getInventory().setArmorContents(null);
                    removePlayerFromEvent(player, true, true);
                }
            }, 3L);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removePlayerFromEvent(Player player, boolean spawn, boolean loadInventory) {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().callEvent(new MiniEventsLeaveEvent(player, plugin.getEventName(),
                plugin.getInfo().inevent.size(), plugin.getTimerMain().getTimeLeft(), plugin.getInfo().inevent));
        if (spawn) {
            teleportPlayerToQuitPoint(player);
        }
        if (loadInventory) {
            loadPlayerInventory(player);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void savePlayerInventory(Player p) {
        FileConfiguration fc = plugin.playerFile(p.getName().toLowerCase());
        ItemStack[] i = p.getInventory().getContents();
        ItemStack[] a = p.getInventory().getArmorContents();
        int slot = 0;
        for (ItemStack stack : i) {
            fc.set(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".inv." + slot, stack);
            slot++;
        }
        int sslot = 100;
        for (ItemStack stack : a) {
            fc.set(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".armor." + sslot, stack);
            sslot++;
        }
        int ii = 0;
        fc.set(p.getName() + ".potion", null);
        for (PotionEffect pp : p.getActivePotionEffects()) {
            String ll = Integer.toString(ii);
            fc.set(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name." + ll + ".type", pp.getType().getName());
            fc.set(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name." + ll + ".level", pp.getAmplifier());
            fc.set(p.getName().toLowerCase() + ".potion.name." + ll + ".duration", pp.getDuration());
            ii++;
        }
        try {
            fc.save(plugin.playerData(p.getName().toLowerCase()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startCountDown(String eventName) {
        plugin.getCountDown().EventWait(eventName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startTimer(String eventName) {
        plugin.getTimerMain().setTime(eventName);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopTimer() {
        plugin.getTimerMain().stop = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void teleportPlayerToQuitPoint(final Player player) throws NullPointerException {
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(settings.getData().getString("quit.world"));
                double x = settings.getData().getDouble("quit.x");
                double y = settings.getData().getDouble("quit.y");
                double z = settings.getData().getDouble("quit.z");
                float yaw = Float.intBitsToFloat(settings.getData().getInt("quit.yaw"));
                float pitch = Float.intBitsToFloat(settings.getData().getInt("quit.pitch"));
                final Location spawn = new Location(w, x, y, z, yaw, pitch);
                player.teleport(spawn);
            }
        }, 20L);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateEventScoreboard(Player player, Integer time, boolean setOrUpdate) {

    }
}
```

Error on line: 24
Implicit super constructor ApiDo() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

How to fix it. Does anyone have any idea? implements gives larger errors because I tried with extends

ApiDo.java

```
package API.Info;

import Mains.MiniEvents;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class ApiDo {
    public MiniEvents plugin;

    public ApiDo(MiniEvents plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    /**
     * @param player - player to be put in spectator mode.
     */
    public void putPlayerInSpectate(Player player){
        plugin.getDo().putPlayerInSpectate(player);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a player from all of the HashSets that are used for events.
     * Player still keeps armor, location, but is not technically in the event anymore.
     * @param player - Player who will be removed from the event.
     */
    public void removePlayerFromEvent(Player player, boolean spawn, boolean loadInventory){
        plugin.getDo().removePlayerFromEvent(player, spawn, loadInventory);
    }

    /**
     * Teleports player to the preset quit point (/setquit).
     * @param player - Player who will be teleported.
     */
    public void teleportPlayerToQuitPoint(Player player) throws NullPointerException{
        plugin.getDo().teleportPlayerToQuitPoint(player);
    }

    /**
     * Saves a player's inventory, potion effects, and armor.
     * @param player - Player who's inventory will be saved.
     */
    public void savePlayerInventory(Player player){
        plugin.getDo().savePlayerInventory(player);
    }

    /**
     * Loads a player's armor, inventory contents, and potion effects.
     * @param player - Player to load inventory for.
     * @throws NullPointerException if player's inventory is not already saved.
     */
    public void loadPlayerInventory(Player player) throws NullPointerException{
        plugin.getDo().loadPlayerInventory(player);
    }

    /**
     * Starts timer on scoreboard.
     * @param eventName - "code" name of an event.
     */
    public void startTimer(String eventName){
        plugin.getDo().startTimer(eventName);
    }

    /**
     * Stops the timer on the scoreboard.
     */
    public void stopTimer(){
        plugin.getDo().stopTimer();
    }

    /**
     * Completely ends any event that is happening.
     * NOTE: This will not remove all player from the event.
     * You muse loop through everyone in the event before ending the event,
     * use heavyRemovePlayerFromEvent and then end the event.
     */
    public void endEvent(boolean removeAll){
        plugin.getDo().endEvent(removeAll);
    }

    /**
     * Updates a player's scoreboard.
     * @param player - The player for whom the scoreboard will be updated.
     * @param time - Time until the event end (wise to use getTimeLeft())
     * @param setOrUpdate - Name of the current, running event.
     */
    public void updateEventScoreboard(Player player, Integer time, boolean setOrUpdate){
        plugin.getDo().updateEventScoreboard(player, time, setOrUpdate);
    }

    /**
     * Starts counting down for an event
     * @param eventName - Name of the event for which the countdown will start for.
     */
    public void startCountDown(String eventName){
        plugin.getDo().startCountDown(eventName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! While everyone here is always willing to help, you are more likely to find a helping hand by narrowing down your question. Consider editing your question to contain only the pieces of code absolutely necessary to convey the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the parent constructor from your constructor using super:

```
public Do(MiniEvents plugin) {
    super(plugin);
    this.plugin = plugin;
}
```

There are other issues with the code - you don't need to create another instance of plugin in the Do class since it is accessible from the ApiDo class.